# How to change Azure Docker VM's docker certificate?

Tags: azure, docker, azure-virtual-machine

I have used `azure vm docker create ...` command to create an azure docker vm, and I want to replace the default docker `ca.pem`, `server-cert.pem` and `server-key.pem` in `/etc/docker.io/` with self-generated certificates.

But I found self-generated certificates will be replaced with the original ones after rebooting azure vm.

Is there any way to change the certificate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an azure-docker-extension bug.

https://github.com/Azure/azure-docker-extension/issues/4

Because the azure-docker-extension `enable` step always copies the certs instead of only starting docker.

Answer (score 2):

An quick solution available from the azure portal (but not very pretty):

1. Add again a Docker extension to your VM and specify the new certificates to use.
2. Validate

=> the extension updates properly but will show an error on the extension itself

3. Restart the VM

=> it should be working fine

Answer (score 0):

You can provide the certificates that you want while you are creating the virtual machine using the parameter -C or its equivalent --docker-cert-dir

```
azure vm docker create -h
help:    Create a VM
help:
help:    Usage: vm docker create [options] <dns-name> <image> <user-name> [password]
help:
help:    Options:
help:      -h, --help                             output usage information
help:      -v, --verbose                          use verbose output
help:      --json                                 use json output
help:      -p, --docker-port [port]               Port to use for docker [4243]
help:      -C, --docker-cert-dir [dir]            Directory containing docker certs [~/.docker/]
help:      -c, --connect                          connect to existing VMs
help:      -l, --location <name>                  the location
help:      -a, --affinity-group <name>            the affinity group
help:      -u, --blob-url <url>                   the blob url for OS disk
help:      -z, --vm-size <size>                   the virtual machine size [small]
help:      -n, --vm-name <name>                   the virtual machine name
help:      -e, --ssh [port]                       the ssh port to enable [22]
help:      -t, --ssh-cert <pem-file|fingerprint>  the SSH certificate
help:      -P, --no-ssh-password                  indicates that the password should be removed when using --ssh-cert
help:      -w, --virtual-network-name <name>      the virtual network name
help:      -b, --subnet-names <list>              the comma-delimited subnet names
help:      -S, --static-ip <ip-address>           the static IP address assigned to the virtual machine
help:      -R, --reserved-ip <name>               the name of the reserved IP address assigned to the virtual machine
help:      -A, --availability-set <name>          the name of availability set to create or use
help:      -s, --subscription <id>                the subscription id
help:      -d, --custom-data <custom-data-file>   CustomData file
```

Comment: In fact, the question is how to replace certificate in azure docker VM, not specify certificate when creating docker VM.

Comment: If I'm not wrong, the command takes the certificates from that folder if they are present and use them to deploy inside the new VM

https://github.com/Azure/azure-xplat-cli/blob/7b684f787343649d00d8f4530f667ccda17dcd8c/lib/commands/asm/vm/vmclient.js#L3885